# How to define arch rule to prohibit that classes catch specific exception types?

Tags: java, exception, archunit

I wish I could define an arch rule prohibiting that classes catch a given exception type. Something like the rule below:

```
noClasses()
    .that()
    .resideOutsideOfPackage("..repository..")
    .should()
    .catchExceptions()
    .that()
    .areAssignableTo(SQLException.class)
```

Is there a way to do that in ArchUnit?

Comment: Currently, it's not possible to check the internals of methods. Therefore exists an open issue: https://github.com/TNG/ArchUnit/issues/260 Feel free to vote for this issue.